# How do I get dropbox working in Ubuntu 16.04 while running in a virtualbox?

Tags: nautilus, dropbox, system-monitor

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in a Virtualbox5, where the host is a windows10 environment.  I installed Dropbox in order to share files.  After booting dropbox, it crashed and told me to restart Nautilus.  I did 'nautilus -q', followed by 'nautilus' to restart.  Dropbox still will not start.  I have gone into system monitor and ended the dropbox and clicked its icon again to restart.  It does not seem to work, but it appears in the system monitor again.  Before it crashed, I was able to link it to my dropbox account, for a few minutes.

Comment: I've had a couple of issues in dropbox/linux which are mostly related to dropbox using all available bandwidth:  if you can get dropbox to open, try setting the preferences->bandwith to something less than the full bandwidth of your internet connection.